# Do I need to include this on my CV?

Tags: resume, applications

I have a very specific situation in which I held two jobs simultaneously but one was part time and one was full time. The part time one I was dismissed at the end of my 3 month probation but I'm still at the full-time job.

Does this need to be included in my CV and if so, how would I tackle this within my CV and at potential interviews?

Comment: How relevant was the part-time job to your intended career path?

Comment: Why are you worried about putting it on your CV or not? Are you expecting some kind of background check that will only go off of your CV without giving you any room for explanation?

Comment: @Cronax I'm unsure how it all works, What you're saying is if I don't put it on or if I do i'll get the chance to explain my side of things regardless or they just wont mention it?

Comment: I think you have a misconception about what a CV is. A CV is a document you send to prospective employers in which you highlight the aspects of yourself what make you suitable to fill the job opening they have. If you have had jobs that were not relevant in any way and you can leave them off without leaving huge holes, there's nothing stopping you. Having said that, *practically every* job has aspects that will be relevant to *practically any* job you're going to apply for, assuming you explain it right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A CV/Resume is not the same as a background check form or application where they ask you to list all jobs or ask for details about why you left previous jobs.

The CV/Resume is a product you use to advertise your skills as they relate to the job you are applying for. If the part time job didn't involve a skill that you want to advertise, then don't include it in the CV.

It does get a little trickier if there will be holes in your work history if you were to only include the one or two jobs that directly relate to the job you are applying for. In that case including other less relevant jobs does show that you do have a long work history. But a part time job, when you already had a full time job doesn't fill holes, so if it doesn't help sell your experience then don't include it in the CV.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I can leave it out then it was just a filler in my employment to temporarily make some money

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mention the part time job.  You won't have to answer the question about your dismissal and you won't give the impression you like to moonlight.

However, if your part-time job has skills/responsibilities/experience that you want to include on your CV, then you'll need to think about how you'll phrase that.

Comment: What if the new employer finds out about the part time job?

Comment: Obviously this depends on the nature of the part-time job.  I used to work part-time in a warehouse part time many years ago to get extra money.  I've never put this on a CV and it's never been an issue.

Comment: It was an arcades, have you ever had to explain it or has any employer ever found out?

Comment: No.  It never came up.